# Problems with signup process

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to sign up a new user to my website, but I am having trouble with the actual signup_process.php page. I currently have sign up form within signup.php and the form action within the signup_process.php. My signup page lists the sports as follows;

```
 <label for="Archery"> Archery</label> <input type="checkbox" id="Archery" name="sport[]"value="1">"
```

My database shows the following;

User table:

user_id 
user_email 
user_username 
user_password 
user_firstname 
user_surname 
user_dob 
user_gender 
user_city 
user_active

User sport table

usersport_id 
usersport_user_id 
usersport_sport_id

Here is the code on my signup_process.php

```
  <?php 
   session_start(); 
   $_SESSION['loggedin'];
   $_SESSION['id'];

   include "includes/connect.php";
 include "includes/lists.php";
 include "includes/functions.php";

 ?> 

  <?php 
  $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username']; 
  $_SESSION['fname'] = $_POST['fname']; 
  $_SESSION['surname'] = $_POST['surname']; 
  $_SESSION['dob'] = $_POST['dob']; 
  $_SESSION['emailaddress'] = $_POST['emailaddress']; 
  $_SESSION['password'] = $_POST['password']; 
  $_SESSION['gender'] = $_POST['gender']; 
  $_SESSION['city'] = $_POST['city']; 
  $_SESSION['sports'] = $_POST['sports'];

  $username = $_POST['username']; 
  $fname = $_POST['fname']; 
  $surname = $_POST['surname']; 
  $dob = $_POST['dob']; 
  $emailaddress = $_POST['emailaddress']; 
  $password = $_POST['password']; 
  $gender = $_POST['gender']; 
  $city = $_POST['city']; 

  $query = "INSERT INTO user ( 
            user_username, 
            user_firstname, 
            user_surname, 
            user_dob, 
            user_email, 
            user_password, 
            user_gender, 
            user_city, 
            user_active
            )

  VALUES( 
  '".$_POST['username']."', 
  '".$_POST['firstname']."', 
  '".$_POST['surname']."', 
  '".$_POST['dob']."', 
  '".$_POST['email']."', 
  '".$_POST['password']."', 
  '".$_POST['gender']."', 
  '".$_POST['city']."', 
  '1' ) "; 

  mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error()); 

  $lastid = mysql_insert_id();

  $sports = $_POST['sports'];

  foreach ($sports as $key => $value){
    $query2 = " INSERT INTO usersport

    (
    usersport_user_id, usersport_sport_id
    )
    VALUES(
    '".$lastid."',
    '".$value."'    
    ) ";

    mysql_query($query2) or die (mysql_error());
  }
```

My signup process seemed to work before I added this which is for the allocation of sports to the new user;

```
      $lastid = mysql_insert_id(); 

       $sports = $_POST['sports'];

  foreach ($sports as $key => $value){
    $query2 = " INSERT INTO usersport

    (
    usersport_user_id, usersport_sport_id
    )
    VALUES(
    '".$lastid."',
    '".$value."'    
    ) ";

    mysql_query($query2) or die (mysql_error());
      }  


   ?>
```

Could anyone please tell me where I've gone wrong?

Comment: How does it not work? Are you seeing an error?

Comment: There is no error, once the submit button is pressed it just refreshes the page. Nothing is wrong with the database and no new user is being created, so I'm out of ideas.

Comment: Sprinkle your code with `echo` statements so that you can find exactly how far it gets and where it dies. Also use `var_dump()` statements to look at your variables and make sure they contain what you think they should contain.